# Accessing OSX 10.7.5 folder from Windows 8

Tags: macos, mac, windows-8

I have a Mac Mini running OSX 10.7.5, I can log into it through a laptop running Windows 7 and browse it's files.

I have another machine running Windows 8, it can see the Mac Mini, but when trying to connect, a "Windows Security" pop-up appears asking me to log in. It automatically adds the DOMAIN to the username field like:

```
Username: <DOMAIN>/mini
Password: .........
```

Authentication fails. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to try:

- Remove the domain name (change the login to just `Mini`) before logging in.
- Use "." instead (`.\Mini`) to represent the target/local computer as the 'domain' to use.

Perhaps check out this SU question: [Is there a simpler way to log into a local account on a domain workstation?](https://superuser.com/questions/246987/is-there-a-simpler-way-to-log-into-a-local-account-on-a-domain-workstation)